# SQL Server Management Studio Setting

Tags: sql-server

How to enable the more accurate help, please ?

Because I have this :

[image]

Comment: That looks normal... what "more accurate help" are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found...
SQL Complete do that job. I thought it was a SQL Server Management Studio option.

With SQL Complete :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I have wondered the same thing, as I expect to receive information similar to this one:

```
REPLACE(string_expression NVARCHAR, string_pattern NVARCHAR, string_replacement NVARCHAR)
```

Unfortunately, there are very only a few options related to intellisense in `SSMS`:

[image]

and you cannot change the way function information is displayed.